# Ocaml Stackoverflow

Tags: ocaml

Why is it that in some functions when I use modules like
List.filter it does not return an error: stack overflow

but when I use

```
let rec filter p l =
match l with
| [] -> []
| hd::tl -> if p hd then hd::(filter p l) else filter p l
```

which has the same functions as List.filter it produces the stack overflow error

Comment: `List.filter` is implemented using [tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). Your `filter` function is not.

Comment: Typically you'd use an accumulator argument so that you can add to the list before making the recursive call in tail position. See [the implementation of `List.filter`](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/list.ml#L239-L245).

Answer (score 1):

Your filter function calls itself recursively with the same list `l`:

```
... then hd::(filter p l) else filter p l
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

This means you never converge towards a solution, you are recursing infinitely.

Reaching Stack Overflow on small inputs is a symptom of such problems.
Likewise, when you write a tail-recursive function you may have non-terminating loops, which is another way to identify when the program is incorrect (some programs are infinite loop on purpose).

In your case you need to use `tl`, the remaining elements from the list. Having something that shrinks at each step of recursion is important if you expect the function to terminate.

Comment: Btw you should have gotten a warning for unused variable `tl`. You should consider those warnings as error until you fully understand what they mean.